# Parse results from Markit On Demand API - JavaScript, AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to parse the response from the API. I can get the whole response but I confused on how to actually parse it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            margin: 10px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click me!</button>
    <div class="text">Replace me!!</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.btn').click(function() {

        $('.text').text('loading . . .');

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            //url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/jsonp?input=NFLX",
            url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL",
            success: function(response) {
                $('.text').html('');

                alert(response);
                alert(response.name);
                alert(response.Name);
                $('.text').text(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is a response I'm currently receiving:

```
myFunction (
{
    "Status": "SUCCESS",
    "Name": "Apple Inc",
    "Symbol": "AAPL",
    "LastPrice": 117.65,
    "Change": 1.05000000000001,
    "ChangePercent": 0.900514579759873,
    "Timestamp": "Mon Oct 24 00:00:00 UTC-04:00 2016",
    "MSDate": 42667,
    "MarketCap": 633950318950,
    "Volume": 23538673,
    "ChangeYTD": 105.26,
    "ChangePercentYTD": 11.7708531255938,
    "High": 117.74,
    "Low": 117,
    "Open": 117.1
}
)
```

Here is a link to Markit On Demand API: http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/

NOTE: I am getting the following error in Chrome and Firefox on the button click, XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

What do I need to do in order to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ajax jsonp call must has `dataType: "jsonp"` & `jsonp: "callback"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      margin: 10px;
      width: 100px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Click me!</button>
  <div class="text">Replace me!!</div>


  <script>
    $('.btn').click(function() {

      $('.text').text('loading . . .');

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/jsonp?input=NFLX",
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL",
        success: function(response) {
          alert(response.Name);
          alert(response.Status);
          $('.text').html('');
          $('.text').text(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Or using Pure JavaScript

```
<script src="http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=workingWithJson"/>
<script>
function workingWithJson(data){
alert(data.Name);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting back key value pairs. If you like you can parse it with JSON.parse .

That will make a JavaScript Object out of that string looking text. Then you can access the content easily.

```
alert(Object.info);
```